# Webrtc build on windows

Tags: python, windows, webrtc

I have followed the below steps in building webrtc in Windows 7 (x64) 
http://www.webrtc.org/native-code/development,

1. Downloaded the depot tools.
2. Run "fetch webrtc" command (It took lot of time to complete this command)

After these commands, I cannot find any build files. Then I ran,

```
python webrtc/build/gyp_webrtc
```

command but it throws me the this error,

```
"ImportError: No module named gyp_chromium"
```

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

The instructions at http://www.webrtc.org/native-code/development seem to be incomplete or out of date. See here: 
https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/build-instructions-windows

Before your fetch, from an administrator prompt do:

```
set DEPOT_TOOLS_WIN_TOOLCHAIN=0
```

And to build:

```
ninja -C out/Release
```